# What is the correct way to use operators in Mongo aggregation pipelines with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I have two documents at this stage in my aggregation pipeline which are:

```
{
    "_id" : "Piers Morgan", 
    "entities" : ["Sexism", "Charlotte Hawkins","Red carpet"]
}
{ 
    "_id" : "Gareth Bale", 
    "entities" : ["Sergio Busquets", "Real Madrid C.F.", "EFL Cup", "Copa del Rey"]
}
```

I wish simply to return a projection which is the id and the size of the array, using Morphia in Java. In Mongo this can be done using:

```
{ $project: { count : {$size : "$entities"} } }
```

In Morphia I have attempted:

```
.project(projection("count", 
    Projection.expression("$size", "entities")));
```

which returns java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject

What is the correct equivalent expression in Morphia?

Comment: Did you try 'expression("$size", "$entities")' ?

Comment: Yes, but the expression method requires a DBObject as its second argument so I'll still get the classCastException. My instinct is that expression isn't the method I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `projection` instead of `expression` like this:

```
.project(projection("count",projection("$size", "entities" )))
```