# Morphia aggregation query to get size of list

Tags: java, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, morphia

I am trying to count the number of elements in a list of each document in a collection, similar to below example. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            item: 1,
            numberOfColors: { $size: "$colors" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

This query would return size of list "colors" in each document.

An equivalent morphia query would be something like this :

```
pipeline =  ds.createAggregation(Abc.class)
                .match(query)
                .project(Projection.projection("count", 
                 Projection.expression("$size","colors")));
```

Error on executing above : java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
I am unable to arrive at an equivalent morphia query to achieve the same.
Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to use operators in Mongo aggregation pipelines with Morphia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45214057/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-operators-in-mongo-aggregation-pipelines-with-mor)

Comment: I tried the  solutions mentioned in this, but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following lines of code

```
project(Projection.projection("count", 
                 Projection.expression("$size","colors"))
```

to

```
Projection.expression("count",new BasicDBObject("$size","$colors")))
```

Comment: or `Projection.expression("count", Projection.projection("$size","colors")))`

Answer (score -1):

Did you try

```
Projection.expression("$size","$colors")));
```

With dollar before colors?

Comment: I just tried with $, and ended up getting error : java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject